# Adjusting minimum width of button in CSS

Tags: html, css

[this is the live server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aihFn.jpg)

I want my button to be **5*5px**, but somehow the minimum width stays at **10px** although I adjusted it in CSS.

Heres my CSS code for the following button :

```
#seat_small {
    min-width: none;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

How can I solve this? :/

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question, not an image

Answer (score 2):

add padding:0 to your css

```css
#seat_small{
min-width: none;
width: 5px;
height: 5px;
border: 0px;
background-color: blueviolet;
border-radius: 2px;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<button id='seat_small'></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding

```css
#seat_small {
  min-width: none;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3em;
}
```

```html
<button id="seat_small"></button>
```